# Why mvn archetype does not work for me?

Tags: maven-3

I'm new on Maven and there's something wrong when I  try to create a now project.

```
E:\java\MavenTest>mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.mycompany.app -DartifacId
=my_app -DarchetypeArtifacId = maven_archetype_quickstart -DinteractiveMode=fals
e
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.108s
[INFO] Finished at: Wed May 15 23:55:57 CST 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 7M/76M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM
 in this directory (E:\java\MavenTest). Please verify you invoked Maven from the
 correct directory. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e swit
ch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MissingProject
Exception
```

The pom.xml should be generated automatically. But it does not work.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root cause are as the following: -

1. There is a space at `-DarchetypeArtifacId = maven_archetype_quickstart`
2. The `archetypeArtifacId` should be `maven-archetype-quickstart`
3. The `-DarchetypeArtifacId` is miss spelling, the correct is `-DarchetypeArtifactId`

Then please try the following: -

```bsh
mvn archetype:generate 
    -DgroupId=com.mycompany.app 
    -DartifactId=my_app 
    -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.maven.archetypes 
    -DarchetypeArtifacId=maven-archetype-quickstart 
    -DarchetypeVersion=1.1 
    -DinteractiveMode=false
```

Please type above command in the single line.

I hope this may help.

Comment: I should really check my params more carefully. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Another answer will be related to the console that you are using to generate the maven project with the archetype:

For example:
With Powershell, the command of the answer doesn't work but with this command is working properly

```
mvn archetype:generate 
    "-DgroupId=com.mycompany.app 
    -DartifactId=my_app 
    -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.maven.archetypes 
    -DarchetypeArtifacId=maven-archetype-quickstart 
    -DarchetypeVersion=1.1 
    -DinteractiveMode=false"
```

because of the problems passing the arguments to the maven command.

This is gonna help somebody, it works for me!